# Not sure if react-native start command works properly

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run existing project with `react-native start` command. I run it in my main folder, where files like `package.json`, `metro.config.js` are located. The only thing I get is:
[image]

When I was looking at basic tutorials I notice that people get different output. In addition when I'm opening android folder in Android Studio and run this app I get:

[image]

My project structure looks like:

[image]

Can somebody help me with running this project?

EDIT1:

While trying to use `react-native run-android` I get:

`Unrecognized command "run-android".` Again after `npm install` I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the react-native project use

```
react-native run-android
```

Make sure your android device and laptop connected to the same network.

Comment: I added EDIT to my post

Comment: use this command npm install -g react-native-cli